# How to get a specific value in firebase-realtime-database in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am having trouble trying to get a specific value in firebase-realtime-database in swift 4.0

Here's the value I want to get that is stored in a varible

```
let value = 12345678
```

Here's what my firebase database looks like

[image]

And I want find the trackId that has the same value as my variable and then get that trackId

I have spent a whole week on this problem I can't seem to solve it any help would be really appreciated.

heres my code so far

```
let questionPostsRef = self.ref.child("questionPosts")
let query = questionPostsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "trackId").queryEqual(toValue: "12345678")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let cat = dict["category"] as! String
        let name = dict["name"] as! String
        print(childSnap.key, cat, name)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard Firebase Query.

To retrieve nodes that contain a child that has a certain value, we query the nodes for the node key in question and specify the value being looked for. They will be returned in a snapshot, and they can be more than one so we need to iterate over each of the returned snapshots.

```
let questionPostsRef = self.ref.child("questionPosts")
let query = questionPostsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "trackId").queryEqual(toValue: "12345678")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let cat = dict["category"] as! String
        let name = dict["name"] as! String
        print(childSnap.key, cat, name)
    }
})
```

and the output would be (assume two were found)

```
-Lu9ma9jsd...  some category   some name
-K999a90k9...  some category   some name
```

This is covered in the Firebase guide: [Work With Lists Of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the Sorting and Filtering section

Now, the question states

> And I want find the trackId that has the same value as my variable and
>   then get that trackId

Of course if you know the trackId already you wouldn't need to fetch it since you already have it. My guess is that you want to return the nodes that match that track ID so you can get to the other data, so that's what the above code does. If you are asking something different, let me know.

EDIT: a followup for the OP. To configure Firebase, this is the typical design pattern within a view controller. From there, you can reference your Firebase throughout this class with self.ref (as in my answer above)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Comment: When I run your code it gives me this error Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn" : "trackId" I configured dict["category"] and dict["name"] to the right values but it stills **doesn't work**

Comment: @umapp That's not really an error - it's a reminder to use indexing with Firebase as it significantly improves query performance. See [Sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). The code in my question **does work** as it was copied and pasted from a project and the output I included was copied and pasted from the console. To test, I entered your exact structure in my Firebase and ran the code. Stating it doesn't work doesn't really help us to help you - be specific, do some digging and check for errors, determine what part isn't working and why.

Comment: @umapp It is not the same for me. I included the console output in my answer to show what you should see in your console. If you are not seeing that, then you've got something else wrong; ensure your structure is identical to what you've included in your question. Note that self.ref points to *my* firebase, so you should set self.ref to point to *your* firebase. Ensure you are authenticated and/or have rules that allow you to read data. Other than that, the code works perfectly.

Comment: I have checked my database structure and it is exactly the same I don't have anything showing up except for a warning in the console that says **Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "trackId" at /questionPosts to your security rules for better performance
**

Comment: Heres what I have written [https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AEAlxAUB16IdYEH3OpLDmH-RtXUhPBfT74l0ITHIAEZjUXiwKnGy-FZwo3zJsWXS76GcsZHfUk7PNxB_XveSi4z51yg] and it gives me the same warning in the console ".indexOn": "trackId"

Comment: @umapp That link is broken and code should be included in your question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To double check my answer, I created a new Firebase project, entered the structure via the Firebase console and copy and pasted the code from my answer into XCode and ran the app. The output matched what I posted and worked correctly. Again, my guess is either you're not authenticated, you're code var references are not pointing to your Firebase or you have a typo. Add the code to your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: could you please send me your xcode folder with the code in it so I can take a look at the code if thats fine with you. You can email me the folder at umappoffical@gmail.com

Comment: I am only 11 yrs old and It is pretty hard for me at this stage :|

Comment: And also I have another question what is self.ref pointing to ??? Because when I run that it gives me an error

Comment: @umapp I have updated my answer with additional information of how to configure Firebase within a class. I would really recommend going through the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) as it covers how to configure it and perform basic functions. There's no need to email you my code as it's all in my answer, and that code exectutes when a button is tapped. I have my Firebase Rules set to .read and .write to true.

Comment: @umapp If my answer helped lead you to a solution, please accept it so it can help others!